# Scroll view subviews with incorrect constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view which has some subviews(buttons, label etc). The constraints on the left and the right are dependent on scroll view. [image]

The contentSize of scroll view changes when I load the view controller. I am able to update the contentSize of the scrollView in viewWillAppear but the constraints of the subviews are not recalculated based on new contentSize. How can I ensure that constraints of the subview are updated when update contentSize of scrollView.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the constraints for the subViews?

Comment: I think you have to use vertical stack view Inside UIScrollview,  it is easy to use if you hide view it automatically adjust space

Comment: no any constraints is required for spacing

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add all the contrains in the layoutSubviews() function
you can have a try

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity i put the example with images there is no any requirement of update constraints

[image]

and whatever you hide automatically solved space issue for example in code if i write

```
btnForgetPassword.isHidden = true
```

i can see out put like

[image]